# Git submodule not getting removed from git repo and not getting pushed successfully

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

A cloned project from git repo `A` was copied in another folder in the local system and tried to be pushed in an another new repository `B`.

All the files except the previous cloned project folder got pushed successfully. The folder in the git repo showing as `[folder_name]@232435`.

I want to remove this remote folder removed from repo, and push the folder successfully in the repo without any sub modules coming into picture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a submmodule into a regular folder, you can:

- [delete that submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309) (but keeping its content) on the disk.
  (Here `asubmodule` represents '`folder_name`')

  ```
  mv asubmodule asubmodule_tmp
  git submodule deinit asubmodule    
  git rm asubmodule
  # Note: asubmodule (no trailing slash)
  # or, if you want to leave it in your working tree
  git rm --cached asubmodule
  mv asubmodule_tmp asubmodule
  ```
- add the files of that (previously submodule) folder to your current repo, and push.

  ```
  git add .
  git commit -m "Add  files from removed submodule"
  git push
  ```